# Erroneous showing of products - WooCommerrce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem with WooCommerce.
I have a store that has a lot of categories and subcategories. Some of them repeat the same names. For example:

```
Store -> Girl -> Blouses
Store -> Girl -> Pants

Store -> Baby -> Girl -> Blouses
Store -> Baby -> Girl -> Pants
```

And now when I add a product to the category "Child -> Girl -> Blouses" it also displays it when I click the category "Girl" - the main one.

How to fix this?

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Comment: If I am understanding your question correctly, then check this page, this solution might solve your issue https://www.templatemonster.com/help/woocommerce-how-to-exclude-subcategory-products-from-category-listing-page.html

Comment: Unfortunately, no. That one hides items from subcategories. My issue is that I have the same subcategory names, but different parents category.

Comment: That's not an issue. it's a feature of the child-parent relationship.

Comment: Really? Whenever else i can use subcategories like that. Now i can't.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you're confused by the same category's name in the child-parent relationship. So even though the names are the same but those categories have unique IDs and slugs.

```
Store -> Girl -> Blouses
```

In the above case, the `Girl` category is your parent category and `Blouses` is a child of the `Girl`, they have a relationship in between. So if you have `Blouses` as the main category somewhere so it's not equal to `Girl -> Blouses`

```
Store -> Baby -> Girl -> Blouses
```

In this next example, `Baby` is your main category and `Girl` is a child of the `Baby` category and `Blouses` is a child of `Girl` but `Girl -> Blouses` and `Baby -> Girl -> Blouses` are not equal.

they all will have a different slug. for example in `Store -> Girl -> Blouses` **Girl** might have slug `girl` but `Store -> Baby -> Girl -> Blouses` **Girl** should have slug-like `girl-baby`

you can see these slugs in urls. So when you'll click on the girl from `Store -> Girl -> Blouses` you'll land on a different page and when you'll Click on `Girl` from `Store -> Baby -> Girl -> Blouses` you'll land on a different page.

so Even though names are the same but categories are not the same if they are in a child-parent relationship.

Comment: Yes that's right. But i dont want have something like "girl-baby" in URL.

Comment: If you're expecting `girl` as your child category slug, that is not possible by default. slug names should be different for all the categories.